# Save and retrieve image from another project in the same solution or common directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with a eCommerce project. in this solution I have 2 project admin part and ui part. the problem is if i store image in admin it work fine in admin project, how can i access it from UI project? or I have to create a common directory in the solution to store and retrieve image, i don't know what to do and how to do, please help me with that.

for save an image my code is ......

```
public static string SaveAnImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
    {
        string fileName = "";
        string vFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)?.ToLower();
        if (fileExtension != null)
        {
            path += vFileName;
            path += fileExtension.ToLower();

            file.SaveAs(path);
            fileName = vFileName + fileExtension.ToLower();
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

and retread an image ....

```
ProductImage = Path.Combine(_mainImagepath , objDataReader["ProductImage"].ToString());
```

now how can I retrieve it from UI project??? Thanks.....

Comment: You should map to the absolute path of file location using `@Url.Content();`

Comment: hwo i get my admin project specific path into UI project? I try using absolute path like F:\Admin\File; but it gives an error, (Cannot access local resources)

Comment: `@Url.Content` resolves a virtual path into an absolute path. Example:
`Url.Content("~/images/image.jpg")` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: I solve this problem by creating virtual directory inside IIS, but in visual studio i just copy the folder from admin and pest it inside UI,

Answer (score 1):

That's really two separate questions:

How do I share the folder in production?

If the sites are on the same server, you can put the shared images pretty much anywhere on the same server. If they are on different servers, you would want to map a network location on both servers to wherever the images are located. In either case, you would then create a virtual directory in IIS on both sites pointing to that shared location.

How do I share the folder in development (i.e. Visual Studio)?

That's a bit more tricky. Basically, you would need to handle it in the same way as in production, but the problem is that IIS Express is not nearly as transparent as full IIS. I've employed the following method in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, but the last time I tried it in 2015, it no longer worked. That may have been fixed by now, though, as it's been a while. Regardless, this is pretty much your only option.

1. Right-click on your solution in the Solution Explorer pane and choose Add > New Website....
2. Click the Browse... button on the resulting window.
3. Click the Local IIS tab.
4. Find the first site in the list that you want to utilize the shared image directory on, and click on it to highlight it.
5. Then, in the top right of the window, click the icon that looks like a folder with a star on it. If you hover over it for a second, it will say "Create New Virtual Directory".
6. In "Alias name:", enter what the path portion within your application should be. For example, if you wanted to find the images at http://localhost:12345/SharedImages, then you would enter SharedImages. Make sure that whatever you choose is not an actual existing directory within your project, though.
7. For "Folder:", browse to the physical directory where the shared images are at on your computer.
8. Uncheck the Create IIS application checkbox.
9. Click OK.
10. Repeat steps 4-9 for any additional sites.
11. Click Cancel on the previous window.
12. Click Cancel again on the original Add New Website Window. (You're not actually going to add a new website to your solution. This is just the only way to access the place where you can create this virtual directory.)

At that point, you should be back to the main Visual Studio window. You won't actually notice any difference in your project/solution, as this was all done in IIS Express. However, if you browse your website and try to load an image under the virtual directory, you should be able to see it in your browser, i.e.:

http://localhost:12345/SharedImages/foo.jpg
If you see the image, everything is working fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am little confused in step 10, i did what you told, but i did not find @Add new website,   I found existing website, and rest are same, Virtual directory is created, but when I run my project IIS run 2 different site, localhost:60225 and localhost:50512, first host can get the file, but second host dose not find it, I don't know what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are couples ways to get file stream from the server. so for static files you may create download link in your views using `@Url.Content("yourfilepath")` or you would create an action to download file stream:

```
public FileResult GetMyFile()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Getting this error: `non-invocable member "File" cannot be used like a method.`

Answer (score 0):

In Razor View you can show it using this code.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("/imagesfolder/image123.jpg")" alt="Image" >
```